# PHPExcel overwrites the rows

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a table, which is sorted out by `item_code` and `status`. I have 3 statuses = 0,1 and 2. I want to make some calculations when each status is finished.

Basically, PXPExcel overwrites the last row of each `status` category. According to the database there is: 4 rows with `status 0`, 1 row with `status 1` and 5 rows with `status 2`. I'm stuck on this part already for couple of days, so any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/4FZjZmt4

Here is the export file output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtMWg.jpg

What I've already tried to do:

```
   /*
    *   Add +1 to each count so it could count last row as well.
    *       1. Start adding +1 to each count outside the main loop.
    *       2. $newCountOne = $countZero + ($countOne +1);
    *       3. $newCountTwo = $newCountOne + ($countTwo +1);
    *       4. if ( $loopCounter == ($countZero +1 ) )
    *       5. To raise $key parameter in "total" row.
    *
    */
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is your main problem.

The loop when adding values to a specific cell has to be this way:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
<?php

    $items = 18;
    $countZero = 4;

    $countOne = 10;

    $countTwo = 4;

    $newCountOne = $countZero + $countOne;
    $newCountTwo = $newCountOne + $countTwo;

    echo "Segundo stop: ".$newCountOne."<br>";
    echo "Tercer stop: ".$newCountTwo."<br>";

    //Starting point.
    $loopCounter = 1;
    $number = 0;


    //Each status has his own background color
   // foreach($items AS $key=>$item) {
      for ($i=0; $i < $items; $i++) { 

         echo "A".($number)."ACTUAL DB VALUE<br>";

        //Main loop
        if($loopCounter == $countZero) {
            echo $loopCounter."<br>";
            $number++;
            //Status0
            echo "Status 0 END <br>";
            echo "A"." cell number: ".($number)." TOTAL"."<br>";
            echo "D"." cell number: ".($number)." VALUE"."<br>";
            echo "E"." cell number: ".($number)." QUANTITY"."<br>";


        } elseif ($loopCounter == $newCountOne) {

            $number++;
            //Status1
            echo "Status 1 END <br>";
            echo "A"." cell number: ".($number)." TOTAL"."<br>";
            echo "D"." cell number: ".($number)." VALUE"."<br>";
            echo "E"." cell number: ".($number)." QUANTITY"."<br>";

        } elseif ($loopCounter == $newCountTwo) {

          $number++;
            //Status2
            echo "Status 2 END <br>";
            echo "A"." cell number: ".($number)." TOTAL"."<br>";
            echo "D"." cell number: ".($number)." VALUE"."<br>";
            echo "E"." cell number: ".($number)." QUANTITY"."<br>";

        }

           //Remove this ELSE!
            /*echo "B".($number + 7)."ACTUAL DB VALUE<br>";
            echo "C".($number + 7)."ACTUAL DB VALUE<br>";
            echo "D".($number + 7)."ACTUAL DB VALUE<br>";
            echo "E".($number + 7)."ACTUAL DB VALUE<br>";
            echo "F".($number + 7)."ACTUAL DB VALUE<br>";
            echo "G".($number + 7)."ACTUAL DB VALUE<br>";
            echo "H".($number + 7)."ACTUAL DB VALUE<br>";
            echo "I".($number + 7)."ACTUAL DB VALUE<br>";
            echo "J".($number + 7)."ACTUAL DB VALUE<br>";
            echo "K".($number + 7)."ACTUAL DB VALUE<br>";
            echo "L".($number + 7)."ACTUAL DB VALUE<br>";*/


        $number++;
        $loopCounter++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation but I can't figure it out, how to transfer my code into your idea loop. Can you help me to figure it out, please?

Comment: I understood what you advised to do and I did it, but unfortunately, it didn't help me. I have the same output with the same 1 overwritten raw after each status section.

Comment: I've played around your code and now I have next results -> http://imgur.com/TTw1KIp but it's still not what I wanted to achieve.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please update your code so I can edit the answer please? Have you tried to use the $number variable in the loop?

Comment: This didn't worked. Here is the output screenshot of to your edited code - http://prntscr.com/4ksq5x

Comment: This my code - which I've worked on (Extended a bit your idea and tried to play around it) - http://pastie.org/9535682 / Screenshot -  http://prntscr.com/4ksrj9

Comment: Updated the code, made a standalone version with echoes.